# Rotating a 3D vector onto the XY-Plane around the x-axis

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, 3d, rotations

I'm currently working with an accelerometer data vector (x,y,z), where I want to "eliminate" the y component of the data while not scaling the vector.
I want to do this by rotating my vector around the x-axis, as it lends to a good result later on in my calculations.

The rotation is done using the following relation:
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\
0 \\
v \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1& 0& 0\\ 
0& z~d& -y~d\\ 
0& y~d& z~d \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x\\ 
y\\ 
z\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where: $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix to be rotated, $\begin{bmatrix} u \\0 \\v \\ \end{bmatrix}$ is the rotated matrix and  $d \triangleq \frac{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}{y^2+z^2}$

However, after implementing the rotation in code, I have come to realise, that I don't always end up with the "shortest" rotation to the xy-plane, though this is what I want. Can somebody suggest a way to ensure I get the shortest rotation?
I realise that an easy fix would simply be to check if z is positive or negative then assigning the sign to v accordingly, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

**The rotation realtion is derrived as follows.**

Starting from a stanard rotation matrix:
$$ 
R_x = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0             & 0 \\ 
0 & \cos(\theta)  & \sin(\theta) \\ 
0 & -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) 
\end{bmatrix} 
\triangleq 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & a & b\\ 
0 & -b  & a
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
I know that i want to keep x unchanged while removing the y component:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a & b\\
0 & -b & a
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
ay + bz \\
-by+az
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\
0 \\
v
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I know that a rotation percerves lenght $u^2 + v^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ implying $v = \sqrt{y^2+z^2}$

From this i can find $a$ and $b$:
$$
\begin{align}
v = \sqrt{y^2 + z^2} &= -by + az \text{  and  } 0 = ay+bz \\
& \Updownarrow\\
a&= z~\frac{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}{y^2+z^2}\\
b &= -y \frac{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}{y^2+z^2} 
\end{align}
$$

leading to:

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\
0 \\
v \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1& 0& 0\\ 
0& z~d& -y~d\\ 
0& y~d& z~d \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x\\ 
y\\ 
z\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: How do you define the "shortest rotation"?

Comment: You should be able to calculate the angle $\theta$ directly and not use a system of equations to find it.  This should be something like projecting the vector into the $xy$-plane and finding the angle this vector makes with the positive $x$-axis there.

Comment: @MichaelBurr -  For a vector rotated in accordance with Rx such that it has 0 as its y component there is going to be a to representations. A representation with a positive z component and a negative z component. By shortest rotation I mean the rotation which causes the original vector to rotate the least. In other words, the rotation which does not cause the sign of z to change.

Comment: As projections aren't length preserving this would not fit my application.
Edit: Ohh are you suggesting finding the angle between the projection and the original, then rotating the original? - Because that might work for me.

Comment: $atan2()$ is your friend in this circumstance.  Something like $\theta = atan2(z, y)$.  No need to normalize.  Then just plug $\theta$ into your rotation matrix.

Comment: @Tpofofn -  AAs my calculation of v (the new z) lands the result in the first quadrant the problem might actually be related to the use of $tan(θ)$. II however struggle to see where the problem should occur as I never use $tan(θ)$ directly or $\frac{Sin θ}{Cos θ}$.

Comment: @Casper, Right.  There are two ways that you can generate a rotation matrix.  The approach that you describe above with unit vectors, and the approach of determining an angle and then generating the rotation matrix.  In your case I think that the angle approach may be clearer.  atan2() should be available in most software packages and gives you a full range result i.e. from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks @Tpofofn I'm going to do that and submit an answer.